# How can I make socket.io work through proxy with react and vite using express backend?

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io, proxy, vite

I'm unable to get socket.io to work through proxy with react+vite (PORT 5173), express (PORT 5002).
I'm receiving an `ERROR: server error` from my current configuration. And my backend isn't receiving any connection attempts.

I want the proxy to make the socket connection using my backend. (I think I'm trying to proxy the namespace e.g. `const socket = io("/api"), to change from /api to http://localhost:5002)`)

Here are the relevant bits from my setup.
My react / client component:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io('/ws', {
  autoConnect: false,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

My vite.config.ts code:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    proxy: {
      '/ws': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5002',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
        rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/ws/, ''),
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

My express server side code:

```
import express, from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  })
);

const port = 5002;

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
   cors: {
     origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
     credentials: true,
   },
});

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {...})

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on Port: ${port}`);
});
```

Whenever I change the path in the vite config and react component from `'ws'` to `'socket'`, the error changes and I get an `Error: xhr poll error`. When this happens my backend receives a  `GET /.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OXLHE7k 404 1.653 ms - 5`

When I remove the proxy from vite and just use the complete url in the react component it works fine and everything functions as expected with no errors,

```
export const socket = io('http://localhost:5002', {
  autoConnect: false,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

However I want to use the proxy now in dev, that's my goal and eventually I will use an nginx proxy in production.

Comment: I get the `Error: xhr poll error` with changing the path in the vite config and react component from `ws` to any of these `so, sock, socket, or socket.io` - But anything else causes an server error and the backend doesn't receive any attempts to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to just use const socket = io(options)
https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#from-the-same-domain

Then the vite config would be:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    proxy: {
      '/socket.io/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5002',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```